# linux crontab "is running" но не работает

Tags: linux, bash, cron, crontab

Добавил в sudo crontab -e:
* * * * * echo hello
и оно в терминал ничего не выводит (ранее пытался запустить скрипт, тоже не работает), ошибок никаких нет.
Результаты различных команд:
sudo service cron status:
* cron is running;
pgrep cron: 
60.
Я мало чего в этот понимаю, поэтому любой совет будет полезен.

Comment: `sudo crontab` создает список для `root` если вам нужно для текущего пользователя - уберите `sudo` и добавте полный путь до скрипта/прогрммы в списке.

Answer (score 4):

cron и не должен ничего выдавать в терминал. Представьте, что вы залогинены в более чем одной сессии, или не залогинены вовсе — куда выдавать?

На самом деле, выдача задач крона, если они что-то сказали в stdout или stderr, пытается отправиться вам почтой. Если вы ничего специально не настраивали, посмотрите в /var/mail/$USER. Но в целом cron придуман не для того, чтобы что-то выводить на экран или, тем более, что-то читать с клавиатуры, а для того, чтобы запускать скрипты/программы по расписанию, в заданное время! :)

Comment: ...а для того, чтобы запускать скрипты/программы по расписанию, в заданное время!

Comment: @misdeed спасиба, кэп! Дополнил.

Comment: После перезапуска терминала(я использую windows 10 subsystem linux), service cron status: is not running? Так и должно быть, что оно останавливается после закрытия терминала?

Comment: @SergiyShcherbina я бы не сказал, что это хоть как-то относится к первоначальному вопросу, а тем более к моему на него ответу. Тем более, что я ничего не знаю про windows.

Comment: Ок. Тогда что можно указать крону вместо скрипта, какую то команду элементарную, чтобы можно было увидеть, что крон делает свою работу?

Comment: @SergiyShcherbina touch /tmp/testfilename

Comment: Огромное спасибо, благодаря вам разобрался